# Only pageshow is fired on the first page, JQM and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 and Phonegap (Build), and no page event is fired on the 'first page' of the app, except `pageshow`...which is very inconvenient, because I need to bind events to `pagecreate`.

Do you know what's happening ?

Thanks

In the Html I tried to add a 'fake' first page : #start-page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">

   <div id="start-page" data-role="page" data-title="App Title">
   </div>

   <!-- WEIGHT-LEVEL PAGE --> 
   <div id="weightlevel-page" data-role="page"> 
   ...
   </div>

   <div id="compute-page" data-role="page"> 
   ...
   </div>

 </div> <!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var isPhoneGap;
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

isPhoneGap = checkIfPhoneGap();

if ( isPhoneGap ) {
    $.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).done( Everything );
} else {
    console.log("NOT Running on PhoneGap!");
    $.when(jqmReadyDeferred).done( Everything );
}

$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    //alert('mobileinit just fired');
    //popShortToast("mobileinit just fired");
    //FastClick.attach(document.body);
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container').pagecontainer();
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});

function onDeviceReady() {
    //popShortToast("deviceReady just fired");
    deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}   

document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady, false);

function Everything() {

todoDuringSplashPage(); //this is where I preprocess the app : retrieving the database from the server, preparing arrays/variables, etc. When it's done, I move to the first page using : $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#weightlevel-page", { transition: "fade" });

$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pagebeforecreate on #weightlevel-page'); });
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pagecreate ($(document).on) on #weightlevel-page'); });
$('#weightlevel-page').on('pagecreate', function(){ alert('pagecreate on #weightlevel-page'); });
$(document).on('pageinit', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pageinit on #weightlevel-page'); });
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pagebeforeshow on #weightlevel-page'); });
$(document).on('pageshow', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pageshow on #weightlevel-page'); });
$(document).on('pageload', '#weightlevel-page', function(){ alert('pageload on #weightlevel-page'); });

}
```

I am moving from splashscreen using :

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#weightlevel-page", { transition: "fade" });
```

Every page event fires on desktop though.

Comment: You sure Everything is running?

Comment: I am 100% sure because that's where I do all write all the bindings and javascript. The app would even run if it was not the case.

Comment: Hmm - is weightlevel-page on your first html page? If so, it may be parsed (created) immediately on the initial page load, which is why it is "too late" to handle the event.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean ? my app is single page app, I have several pages with data-role=page... I am editing the question with cleaner html.

Comment: What I meant is -on your first page load, JQM sees those 3 pages and creates them *immediately*, so by the time you do the event listener, it is too late- the page is already created.

Comment: I think it's the way to go for single-page apps with JQM...what do you suggest ?

Comment: Normally I don't put it all in one index.html. I don't think the JQM team recommends that either. Use a unique file for each page. You don't lose the SPA.

Comment: oh ok, I thought it was the opposite. Indeed, you seem to be right about the fact that it may be a timing issue, because if I move the listeners up in the js file they fire !  Maybe I have to revise my code...

Comment: I edited the question so you can see that there is a function `todoDuringSplashPage` that is executed before the event bindings.... Should I put this function at the end of Everything() ? so that I am sure that when I 'move' to #weightlevel-page, the event are well bound ?

Comment: I don't think it will help for the reasons I said above - you are still loading the pages *immediately* since they are in index.html. I'd just move them out.